# How to make VS2010 C++ see the windows 7 64bit SDK?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Been trying for 2 hours now, and theres no luck.  I wanna make it so I got templets for a win64 app (Not .net) but I can't find where to add platforms. Please help?

Comment: I've managed this by adding SDK to the include and library directories, which is fine for one-off, but I too would like to know a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "Win64" API.  There are just 32-bit Win32 apps and 64-bit Win32 apps, and the only difference is <strike>a compiler/linker option</strike> which compiler/linker are used (different directory).

The Win32 templates work just fine for 64-bit development.

---

While (much) earlier versions of Visual C++ shipped with a private copy of SDK headers, VS2010 installs a version of the Windows SDK and uses an environment variable to find SDK headers during build.  So installing a new SDK, as long as it updates your environment variables, is automatically found by Visual C++ projects at build-time.  (With the old Visual C++ versions, the SDK installer was supposed to edit the tool paths in the Visual Studio section of the registry, which could occasionally fail)

Comment: Then why is my program in 32 bit after using the win32 template?

Comment: And how do I get it to 64 bit?

Comment: @CyanPrime: Build menu -> Configuration Manager -> Add -> pick "x64" from the list -> Ok